# How to re-part my disk

Tags: disk

I installed ubuntu alongside my Gnome Ubuntu 14.04 OS ans halfed my storage. I now don't use Gnome and thus want to re-part my disk, so that the whole disk is for Ubuntu. How do I do this ??

Answer (score 0):

You cannot rezise your partition if it is mounted and being used. Do this:

1. Put the Ubuntu live CD and boot with it
2. Open GPARTED
3. Destroy the other partition you won't use (Other OS)
4. Resize your ubuntu partition to fill up the unpartitioned part or your HD

I usually use /home in a different partition, but you can do it anyway.

Comment: Depending on the current setup you may need to also run [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) or something to fix boot issues caused by moving the partitions.